# How Concurrent blocks can run a single GPU streaming multiprocessor?

Tags: cuda

I was studying about the CUDA programming structure and what I felt after studying is that; after creating the blocks and threads, each of this blocks is assigned to each of the streaming multiprocessor (e.g. I am using GForce 560Ti which has14 streaming multiprocessors and so at one time 14 blocks can be assigned to all the streaming multiprocessors). But as I am going through several online materials such as this one :

http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/cluster/nvidia/GPU+CUDA.pdf

where it has been mentioned that several blocks can be run concurrently on one multiprocessor. I am basically very much confused with the execution of the threads and the blocks on the streaming multiprocessors. I know that the assignment of blocks and the execution of the threads are absolutely arbitrary but I would like how the mapping of the blocks and the threads actually happens so that the concurrent execution could occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Streaming Multiprocessors (SM) can execute more than one block at a time using *Hardware Multithreading*, a process akin to [Hyper-Threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

The [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) describes this as follows in Section 4.2:

> **4.2 Hardware Multithreading**
>
> The execution context (program counters, registers, etc) for each warp
> processed by a multiprocessor is maintained on-chip during the entire
> lifetime of the warp. Therefore, switching from one execution context
> to another has no cost, and at every instruction issue time, a warp
> scheduler selects a warp that has threads ready to execute its next
> instruction (the active threads of the warp) and issues the
> instruction to those threads.
>
> In particular, each multiprocessor has a set of 32-bit registers that
> are partitioned among the warps, and a parallel data cache or shared
> memory that is partitioned among the thread blocks.
>
> The number of blocks and warps that can reside and be processed
> together on the multiprocessor for a given kernel depends on the
> amount of registers and shared memory used by the kernel and the
> amount of registers and shared memory available on the multiprocessor.
> There are also a maximum number of resident blocks and a maximum
> number of resident warps per multiprocessor. These limits as well the
> amount of registers and shared memory available on the multiprocessor
> are a function of the compute capability of the device and are given
> in Appendix F. If there are not enough registers or shared memory
> available per multiprocessor to process at least one block, the kernel
> will fail to launch.

Comment: I've also read this part a bit earlier while trying to answer the OP, but I don't find it convincing. In particular, what happens if you have 8 blocks, each with 4 threads. Can they form a warp, thus executing in parallel?

Comment: Each block will have 1 warp. Each warp will have 4 active threads and 28 disabled threads.